# I cant display the second media:content with simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml

It seems that I can't retrieve the second media:content, the one with the `width="460"` on it.

```
<item>
   <title>...</title>
   <link>...</link>
   <description>...</description>

   <category domain="...">title</category>
   <category domain="...">Benjamin Netanyahu</category>
   <category domain="...">Judaism</category>
   <category domain="...">Religion</category>

   <pubDate>Mon, 23 Jul 2018 07:00:27 GMT</pubDate>

   <media:content width="140" url="**(i can retrieve this image)**">
      <media:credit scheme="urn:ebu">Photograph: Author 1</media:credit>
   </media:content>

   <media:content width="460" url="**(but i cant retrieve this one)**">
      <media:credit scheme="urn:ebu">Photograph: Author 2</media:credit>
   </media:content>

   <dc:creator>Touma-Sliman</dc:creator>
   <dc:date>2018-07-23T07:00:27Z</dc:date>
</item>
```

Here is my current code:

```
 foreach ($xml->channel->item as $key=>$item)
 {
    $results = (string)$item[0]->children('media', true)->content->attributes()['url'];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

`...->content->...` is short-hand for `...->content[0]->...`, so you're only ever asking for the first instance of that node.

Instead, you need to loop over the `->content` nodes in exactly the same way as you are looping over the `->item` nodes:

```
foreach ( $item->children('media', true)->content as $content )
```

Or if for some reason you knew you explicitly wanted the second node, you could ask for item `[1]`:

```
$second_url = (string)$item->children('media', true)->content[1]->attributes()['url'];
```

(I've replaced `$item[0]` with `$item`, because that variable already represents a single instance of `<item>` each time around the loop.)